# How to encrypt a file in Github public repo while still allowing for use?

Tags: github, encryption, secret-key

I am trying to create a public Github repo that uses Google OAuth and my secret credentials to allow the user to sign in and let my app access private YouTube data.

I want to make this repo available for anyone to clone and use and in order for that to work, they need my secret key, but I do not want to expose this as I risk security breaches.

This is the structure of the secret file.

```
{
installed": {
    "client_id": "xxxx",
    "project_id": "xxx",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxx",
    "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost"]
  }
}
```

How do I make these keys secure but still usable, and has this been done before successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, that's not how it works. Either set up a server to handle anything related to YT, or tell whoever cloning your project to use their own credential.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like Mozilla SOPS? - https://blog.thenets.org/how-to-commit-encrypted-files-to-git-with-mozilla-sops/